# IEnumerable к производному типу

Tags: c#

Использую *CommonOpenFileDialog* из *Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack*.
С его помощью можно реализовать multiselect директорий.
Свойство **FileNames** возвращает *IEnumerable* коллекцию.

Вот код, где все это происходит:

```
List<string> selectedPath2 = null;
var cofd = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
cofd.IsFolderPicker = true;
cofd.Multiselect = true;
var result2 = cofd.ShowDialog();
if (result2 == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
{
    selectedPath2 = (List<string>)cofd.FileNames; //здесь ошибка приведения типов
}
```

Хотелось бы приводить ее к *List'у*, но ничего не получается, хотя *List<>* реализует *IEnumerable*. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приведение не работает, потому что в [`FileNames` лежит не `List<string>`](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/master/source/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/CommonFileDialogs/CommonFileDialog.cs#L29).

```
protected IEnumerable<string> FileNameCollection
{
    get
    {
        foreach (string name in filenames)
        {
            yield return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Если нужен именно `List<string>` можно воспользоваться методом [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
selectedPath2 = cofd.FileNames.ToList();
```

Либо наоборот, пользоваться в своей части программы `IEnumerable<string>`, а не списком.

Comment: Спасибо! Я почему-то думал, что можно привести к List'у без метода, раз List реализует IEnumerable

Comment: @Ep1demic, то, что `List` реализцует `IEnumerable`, значит, что объект типа `List` всегда может быть сконвертирован в `IEnumerable`. Обратное преобразование возможно лишь в таком случае `List->IEnumberable->List`. В вашем коде отсутствует первый шаг, что оставляет `IEnumberable->List`, которое, в общем случае, не может быть осуществлено.